# (403) There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to connect a PHP App located on an online server to Google Drive API, I have given my API key the right credentials as seen below:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    Class googleDriveAPIController Extends baseController {


        /**
         * Retrieve a list of File resources.
         *
         * @param Google_Service_Drive $service Drive API service instance.
         * @return Array List of Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile resources.
         */
        function retrieveAllFiles($service) {
          $result = array();
          $pageToken = NULL;

          do {
            try {
              $parameters = array();
              if ($pageToken) {
                $parameters['pageToken'] = $pageToken;
              }
              $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);

              $result = array_merge($result, $files->getItems());
              $pageToken = $files->getNextPageToken();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
              $pageToken = NULL;
            }
          } while ($pageToken);
          return $result;
        }




        public function index() {

        set_include_path('google-api-php-client/src');
        require_once(get_include_path() . '/Google/autoload.php');
        require_once(get_include_path() . '/Google/Client.php');
        require_once(get_include_path() . '/Google/Service.php');
        require_once(get_include_path() . '/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php');
        require_once(get_include_path() . '/Google/Service/Drive.php');

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName("My Application");
        $client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyAmWcZArf7NCk4d65HoKZzLENCJ6cx9fNg");
        $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);           
        $this->retrieveAllFiles($service);      

        }
}
```

I get the following error:

> An error occurred: Error calling GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=AIzaSyAmWcZArf7NCk4d65HoKZzLENCJ6cx9fNg:
>   (403) There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your
>   API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use
>   the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if
>   request from this IP or referer should be allowed.

I have granted access to this application so not sure what is going on here, anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Many Thanks

Comment: are you running the script from http://shabazejaz.co.uk/googledriveAPI ?

Comment: Yes, I even put in  shabazejaz.co.uk/* so that it would work for everything under that domain, still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need to fix the restriction.  You must be running it from an incorrect location.

```
*shabazejaz.co.uk/*
```

Might be a better value.  You will need to test it.

**On a side note:**

Browser API key  is used for accessing public data.

> [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) Lists the user's files.

For you to be able to run file.list you are going to have to be authenticated using Oauth2 or a service account.  Browser API key isn't going to work.